# Count rows by foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need a little help some a sql queries. To summarise, I have 2 tables. `Player` (which represents a sports player) and a `Goal` (which represents a goal a player scores). A Player can have many Goals and linked using a foreign key on the goal table (`player_id`).

What I want to do is get a list of "top scoring players" (top 5), but I have no idea where to start to do this using MySQL. In PHP I'm getting all the goals, then with each goal counting how many player_id's appear and group them like that (then with the array of players and their goal count, trimming the array down to 5). It works, but I'm almost positive I can do the counting in MySQL.

How should I approach this?

**EDIT**

Tables look like

Player

```
ID
Name
```

Goal

```
player_id
scored_against
time
```

Comment: Can you add the table structure

Comment: Some schemas, etc, would be nice... Anywho, what you can do in sql is something like this: `select player_id, sum(goal) as goals from Goal GROUP BY player_id ORDER BY goals desc limit 5`

Comment: This is almost right, but the `sum()` part is adding up the goals. I need it to count the rows.

Comment: ...actually replacing sum with count works! Would you mind posting your response as a reply so I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(PLAYER.PLAYER_ID) as Goals,PLAYER_NAME 
FROM PLAYER, GOAL 
WHERE GOAL.PLAYER_ID = PLAYER.PLAYER_ID
GROUP BY GOAL.PLAYER_ID
ORDER BY Goals DESC
LIMIT 5
```